# Println changes capacity of a slice

Tags: go

Consider the following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := []byte("a")
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(cap(x) == cap([]byte("a"))) // prints false

    y := []byte("a")
    fmt.Println(cap(y) == cap([]byte("a"))) // prints true

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zv8KQekaxH8

Calling simple Println with a slice variable, changes its capacity. I suspect calling any function with variadic parameters of `...interface{}` produces the same effect. Is there any sane explanation for such behavior?

Comment: See: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24972

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation is, like *bradfitz* point in [github](http://github.com/golang/go/issues/24972), if you don't use `make` to create a slice, the compiler will use the cap it believes convenient. **Creating multiple slices in different versions, or even the same, can result on slices of different capacities.**

In short, if you need a concrete capacity, use `make([]byte, len, cap)`. Otherwise you can't trust on a fixed capacity.